# One controller's scope blocks other scopes in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a set of tabs which all have a directive in them:

```
<div class="col-md-9 maincols" id="formEditor">
    <tabset>
        <tab heading="New subscriber" select="isSelected('newSub')">
            <new-subscriber></new-subscriber>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Existing subscriber" select="isSelected('existingSub')">
            <existing-subscriber></existing-subscriber>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Landing page" select="isSelected('landing')">
            <landing-page></landing-page>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

All these 3 directives have been defined similarly like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('newSubscriber', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'scripts/newsubscriber/newsubscriber.html',            
            controller: 'newsubscriberCtrl'
        };
    }); //... and so on
```

I am (probably wrongly) under the impression that because I have set `scope: {}` for all the directives, they should now have completely isolated scopes and leave each other alone.

**But that is not the case and bindings from the first directive's controller manage to stop values in the second or third controller from being binded**

for example in newsubscriberCtrl I have:

```
app.controller('newsubscriberCtrl', ["$scope", "$routeParams", "UserMessages", "FormProvider", function ($scope, $routeParams, UserMessages, FormProvider) {

        $scope.formId = $routeParams.formId;

        var newSubscriberForm = new FormProvider.Form($scope);

        angular.extend($scope, newSubscriberForm);

        $scope.title = UserMessages.exampleText.genericPageTitle;
        $scope.description = UserMessages.exampleText.genericPageDescription;

        $scope.validationMessages = {
            contactNotSaved: UserMessages.validationMessages.contactNotSaved,
            contactCreatedOk: UserMessages.validationMessages.contactCreatedOk,
            contactNotCreated: UserMessages.validationMessages.contactNotCreated,
            requiredField: UserMessages.validationMessages.requiredField,
            passwordMismatch: UserMessages.validationMessages.passwordMismatch,
            isOpen: false
        }

    }]);
```

which is overriding the similar object in existingSubscriber controller:

```
app.controller('existingsubscriberCtrl', ["$scope", "$routeParams", "UserMessages", "FormProvider", function ($scope, $routeParams, UserMessages, FormProvider) {

        $scope.formId = $routeParams.formId;

        var existingSubscriberForm = new FormProvider.Form($scope);

        angular.extend($scope, existingSubscriberForm);

        $scope.title = UserMessages.exampleText.genericPageTitle;
        $scope.description = UserMessages.exampleText.genericPageDescription;

        $scope.validationMessages = {
            contactNotSaved: UserMessages.validationMessages.contactNotSaved,
            contactSavedOk: UserMessages.validationMessages.contactSavedOk,
            requiredField: UserMessages.validationMessages.requiredField,
            passwordMismatch: UserMessages.validationMessages.passwordMismatch,
            isOpen: false
        }

    }]);
```

So in the view of both directives `<pre>{{validationMessages | json }}</pre>` the validationMessages object has the props of the first controller.

Why is this happening? Am I missing to understand a concept here? How Can I isolate these controllers from each other and comfortably have similar props in the controllers without them affecting each other?

Side note: I strongly want to avoid having to prefix everything on all scopes with their controller name, e.g `$scope.newSubscriber.validationMessages` and so on... as that would defeat the whole point pretty much as I will effectively one big controller for the whole tab section and directives would also be pointless.

- Angular is on v.1.3.0-beta.11
- angular-ui-bootstrap is on v.0.10.0

Comment: By just looking at your code, it is very strange that one isolated directive can access another one's. Before, I go further and test it, what is the version of angular.js  and angular.bootstrap you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reuse the same controller `newsubscriberCtrl` in /app/scripts/formbanner/formbanner.js:

```
.directive('formBanner', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: 'scripts/formbanner/formbanner.html',
        controller: 'newsubscriberCtrl'
    };
});
```

The `existingSubscriber` directive have the `formBanner` as a child directive, plus the `formBanner` directive doesn't have an isolated scope.

Therefore, the `$scope` that get injected into the `newsubscriberCtrl` of `formBanner` is the same as the scope of the `existingSubscriber`!!

I've tried removing the controller property in the `formBanner` directive and I saw it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks runTam it must have been a long day effect

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('newSubscriber', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { someValue = "&validationMessages" },
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'scripts/newsubscriber/newsubscriber.html',            
            controller: 'newsubscriberCtrl',
            link: function (scope, iElm, iAttrs) {
               var x = scope.someValue();
               // x = your messages              
            }
        };
    });
```

In your controller

```
$scope.someValue
```

EDIT Disclaimer: this is sort of from memory. When I was facing something similar I felt this to be rather enlightning:
http://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/

Comment: I did try that but didn't help. Now included more info and a demo link. sorry it's all a bit too much to make a fiddle.